# Angular Routing Not Found Component issue with Javascript files root directory

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I'm having a strange issue with some javascript files in my index.html file.  I recently added a Not Found Component to my project by adding the following route:

```
{ path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },
```

My Not Found Component works great if I add text to the end of the url.  But if I add a "/" to the route, my javascript files change the path where the .html is looking for the javascript files.  These javascript files are all located in the src directory of the project.

A snippet of my code:
index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>EEOI</title>
  <!-- <base href="/"> -->
  <script src="env.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

For example, I have a route called 'instructions'.  If I'm on http://localhost:4200/instructions, all the browser correctly looks in http://localhost:4200/env.js for env.js, and everything loads correctly.

However, if I type a route that doesn't exist, like "http://localhost:4200/instructions/foo", my browser gets javascript loading errors because it's trying to load env.js from "http://localhost:4200/instructions/foo/env.js".

How can I make the browser always load the .js file from the root directory of the project?

Comment: Maybe just <script src="/env.js"></script> ?

Answer (score 0):

In your file `app-routing.module.ts` you could add a redirection to the base route as follows:

```
    //previous code
    
    const routes: Routes = [{
      path:'instructions',
      component:NotFoundComponent
    },{
      path:'instructions/:var',
      pathMatch:'prefix',
      redirectTo:'instructions'
    }]
    
    // more code
```

However this redirection rule is rather a workaround as it is not allowing to start your .js code from a different address than http://localhost:4200/instructions.